# How to compare array with keys in a hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm building a simple encrypter to encrypt a string in ruby.

```
cipher = {"a" => "6", "b" => "$", "c" => "X"...}
key_word = "secret"
key_word.split(//)
=> ["s", "e", "c", "r", "e", "t"]
```

How can I compare the key_word characters with the keys in my cipher hash and return them?

Comment: Please edit your question to correct the code: `key_word.split(//) #=> ["s", "e", "c", "r", "e", "t"]`. Yes, we know what you mean, but you need to do it right. Your question could be improved by expanding `cipher` to include keys for all the letters in "secret" (and a few others, and ditch the dots), so readers could test their code more easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [`Rexexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) and the hash argument version of [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
encrypted = key_word.gsub(Regexp.union(cipher.keys), cipher)
```

Comment: μ, I agree with you that there's no point in converting the string to an array. No lambda?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No need for a lambda here, I'm using a Hash (which is really just a function whose domain is the set of its keys...) to represent the function this time :)

Answer (score 2):

One form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) takes a hash as an argument:

```
encrypted = key_word.gsub(/./, cipher)
```

So just match each character and replace it with its value in `cipher`. If `cipher` does not have a key equal to the character, the character is left unchanged.

Comment: the resulit is "X".If cipher does not have a key equal to the character, the character is replaced as blank

Comment: i don't follow what you mean by `"X:`, I've assumed `cipher` has a key for each character, which seems to me to be a requirement of any ciper worth its salt. A message decoded, "I've set the timer to go off at _o'clock", wouldn't be of much use.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
cipher = {"a" => "6", "b" => "$", "c" => "X"}

'abc'.tr(cipher.keys.join, cipher.values.join)
#=> "6$X"
```

or with split  and join (what might be much slower):

```
'abc'.each_char.map { |char| cipher[char] }.join
#=> "6$X"
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
ciper.values_at(*key_word.split(//)).join
```